Imprecise type inference of pipe and compose functions in TypeScript
I have defined pipe and compose functions, each able to compose exactly two functions into a new one, with the only difference of the call order upon application to the argument.
Both functions are generic and I was hoping I can make the product-function to be strongly-typed, yet something is off and the result function type is inferred incorrectly.
Questions:

Is it a limitation of the language or I am doing something wrong?
How do I fix it, if it's possible in TypeScript?

function pipe<X, Y, Z>(first: (x: X) => Y): (f2: (y: Y) => Z) => (x: X) => Z {
  return function (second: (y: Y) => Z): (x: X) => Z {
    return function (x: X): Z {
      return second(first(x));
    };
  }
}

function compose2<X, Y, Z>(second: (y: Y) => Z): (f2: (x: X) => Y) => (x: X) => Z {
  return function (first: (x: X) => Y): (x: X) => Z {
    return function (x: X): Z {
      return second(first(x));
    };
  }
}

Usage
function numToStr(n: number): string { return n.toString(); }
function strToLen(s: string): number { return s.length; }

// Inferred as (x: number) => unknown
// Should be (x: number) => number
const f1 = pipe(numToStr)(strToLen);

// Inferred as(x: unknown) => number
// Should be (x: number) => number
const f2 = compose(strToLen)(numToStr);


It's not really a "limitation" of the language so much as the normal behavior: type parameters are instantiated with arguments when you call the function. They are not "delayed" or "deferred". So if you call pipe() then X, Y, and Z will be inferred. But Z cannot be inferred there, so you get unknown. All you need to do is move the type parameters to the proper scope, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what's missing?

see the linked q/a above.

Instead of hard coding the return type of each function. Allow typescript to infer it and ensure the generic parameters are used not too early:
function pipe<X, Y>(first: (x: X) => Y) { // <-- Avoid <Z> here is too early
  return function <Z>(second: (y: Y) => Z) { // <-- <Z> is needed here
    return function (x: X) {
      return second(first(x));
    };
  }
}

function compose<Y, Z>(second: (y: Y) => Z) {// <-- Avoid <X> here is too early
  return function <X>(first: (x: X) => Y) {// <-- <X> is needed here
    return function (x: X): Z {
      return second(first(x));
    };
  }
}

function numToStr(n: number): string { return n.toString(); }
function strToLen(s: string): number { return s.length; }

const f1 = pipe(numToStr)(strToLen);
const f2 = compose(strToLen)(numToStr);

The problem is that in your first call pipe(numToStr) TypeScript can infer x from n as number and Y from the return as string but there is no Z at this point so it is infered as unknown. TypeScript don't try to re-infer it later when the second call happens, it stays as unknown.

I will definitely accept this answer (as it works) if you can give a brief explanation of why your approach works, while mine doesn't. The move of the  and  to the inner function is interesting, but I don't understand why it's necessary.

@IgorSoloydenko pipe(numToStr) can be applied to other functions that take strings, there isn't a unique Z until you pass the second function

I have added a few more details.
